# Passing a reference of a parent Form to a child UserControl in c++

Tags: c++, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying for a while now to pass a pointer of parent `Form1` to child user control `oP2_settings`.

At this point, I am trying to implement the user control for the basic settings functionality. Some of this requires interacting with elements of parent (Status strip, window title, such things).

I managed to implement this by both:

- forwarding pointer to "this" in User Control constructor from `Form1`
- executing a separate void function `setParent` that takes a parameter of `Form1^`

However, I cannot find any solution that doesn't break the designer.
For example, when I remove forward reference to class `Form1`, then the designer works, but compiler naturally won't allow the compilation to proceed on grounds of undefined identifier.

When I get the program to run, designer acts weird. Depending on situation, there are about 4 different errors from *'Events cannot be set on the object passed to the event binding service'* through *'Method not found'* or occasionally the designer loads, but instead of showing User Control in the appropriate tab, it shows `Form1` in both (user control as a single element).

Is there any way I can get this to work both run time/compile time and design time? I don't fancy having to comment in and comment out my lines every time I want to compile/move an element.

This is in C++ Windows Forms application, I am using VS2010.

Comment: It sounds to me like you user control is bound too tightly to your parent window.  You may want to consider having the user control expose events that the parent form registers for.  So, instead of `m_parent->SetWindowTitle(someString)`, you would use `if(statusChangedFunc != NULL) statusChangedFunc(someString)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a too tightly-coupled designed. Your user control cannot live without its parent. You should use events instead of passing references between parent and child.

If something changes in your user control and the parent needs to update, then create an event in the user control for that and fire it. The parent in turn installs a handler for the event and performs appropriate actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am having trouble finding a good reference as to how to do it.

It seems to me, from what I can see in the designer-made code, that there is an event handler registered as here:  
this->but_connectNow->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &oP2_settings::but_connectNow_Click)

I've tried changing the reference to a method in other class, but that doesn't work, unsurprisingly.

What am I to do now? I don't think I can simply register a handler in Form1 class, since event is instance specific.
Am I to create a public(static?) event fired from handler method in class?

Comment: In the end I found a nice enough reference on MSDN (of all places).

So apparently yes, the answer lies in firing a public event from the method that is registered as event handler for the click of the button.

Link to the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should make modifications on your references directly from your parent form. You can do this by triggering the parent method which does this on button click in the User Control.

Here is a working Visual C++ code using delegates / events:

```
//UserControl.h
namespace YourNamespace {

delegate void ClickEventHandler(String ^); //instead of "String^" place your / other parameters

public ref class YourUserControl: public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
{

public:
    event ClickEventHandler^ OnClick;   // declare the event OnClick

    ExaminationTabControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
...

#pragma endregion

private: System::Void btn1_onClick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        his->txtFirstName->Text + " " + this->txtLastName->Text;
                 OnClick("The string to be sent.");
             }
}
};
```

And in your Parent form:

```
//Parent.h
namespace YourNamespace {
...
#pragma endregion

public: void methodToBeTriggered(String^ yourString) {
            this->txtBox->Text = yourString; // now you have access to all the references
}

private: void methodWhereYouCreateUserControlInstance() {
             YourUserControl^ userControl= gcnew YourUserControl();
             userControl->OnClick += gcnew ClickEventHandler(this, &ParentClassName::methodToBeTriggered);
}
};
```